# How to set a parameter in a Object.keys().map() function as a key in a new object?

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

I want to create an object inside a mapping function and assign the parameter passed to it as a key for a new object

```
Object.keys(responseList[1].data).map((id) => {
               var name = { id : "Apple" };
           });
```

Problem is the `id` parameter is said to be unused when I try set it as a key in an object like this. I tried putting curly brackets around the key and other things to try make it reference the parameter but nothing worked. How do I achieve this?

Comment: your .map callback should also return something

Comment: `var name = {}; name[id]="Apple";` or `var name = { [id]: "Apple" }`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `[]` braces to get key. Like this `var name = { [id] : "Apple" };`